# Arm Template copy inside array

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to add array of emails to ActionGroup. In ARM template I provide the array of emails:

```
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroup_emails":{
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
```

Then inside ActionGroup resource I iterate the emails in emailReceivers property to create receivers:

```
{
            "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('appInsights_actionGroup_name')]",
            "location": "Global",
            "properties": {
                "groupShortName": "EmailAg",
                "enabled": true,
                "emailReceivers": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(split(parameters('actionGroup_emails'),'@')[0],'_EmailAction')] ",
                        "emailAddress": "[parameters('actionGroup_emails')[copyIndex()]]",
                        "useCommonAlertSchema": false,
                        "copy":{
                            "name":"emails",
                            "count":"[length(parameters('actionGroup_emails'))]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

To my undestanding I cannot do this as I am not iterating neither resource nor property as per doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties). So I am confused :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just pass an array of strings like you say, you need to do this:

```
"properties": {
    "copy": [
         {
             "name": "emailReceivers",
             "count": "[length(parameters('actionGroup_emails'))]",
             "input": {
                 "name": "[concat(split(parameters('actionGroup_emails'),'@')[0],'_EmailAction')] ",
                 "emailAddress": "[parameters('actionGroup_emails')[copyIndex()]]",
                 "useCommonAlertSchema": false
             }
         }
     ]
}
```